# I want to replace texts in my file

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

My file looks like:

```
NODE_13_length_50291_cov_8.067223 GTTGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_25_length_22118_cov_8.258986 TATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_36_length_15273_cov_5.283743 TGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAG
```

I want to change this to:

```
NODE_13 GTTGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_25 TATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_36 TGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAG
```

If possible, I also want to make a log file which looks like:

```
NODE_13_length_50291_cov_8.067223   NODE_13
NODE_25_length_22118_cov_8.258986   NODE_25
NODE_36_length_15273_cov_5.283743   NODE_36
```

Which command would work for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome! I edited the question to clarify, tell me if it's ok.

Comment: Are you using spaces or tabs as field separators?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part you can try this:

```
sed 's/_length.*[[:blank:]]\([ACGT]*\)$/ \1/' file
```

Output:

```
NODE_13 GTTGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_24 TATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_36 TGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAG
```

For the second part:

```
sed 's/\(^NODE_[0-9]*\)\(_.*\) [ACGT]*$/\1\2 \1/'
```

Output:

```
NODE_13_length_50291_cov_8.067223 NODE_13
NODE_24_length_22118_cov_8.258986 NODE_24
NODE_36_length_15273_cov_5.283743 NODE_36
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I just tried this out, but the result of the first command looks like:

NODE_13_length_50291_cov_8.067223 GTTGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_25_length_22118_cov_8.258986 TATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_36 TGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAG
It only changed the third row. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: @S.Hokyung I copied the text from the post and it works for me. I added a `[[:blank:]]` in the first command, see the updated answer, let's see if that solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
sed 's|_length.*[0-9]||g' file.txt
```

Output:

```
NODE_13 GTTGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_25 TATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_36 TGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAG
```

Second:

```
awk '{print $1,substr ($1,1,7)}' log_file.txt
```

Output

```
NODE_13_length_50291_cov_8.067223 NODE_13
NODE_25_length_22118_cov_8.258986 NODE_25
NODE_36_length_15273_cov_5.283743 NODE_36
```

If you want to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's|_length.*[0-9]||g' log_file.txt

awk -i inplace '{print $1,substr ($1,1,7)}' log_file.txt
```

To do it with `awk`, you need to have version 4.2 or later.

Comment: The first command works well, but the second part is not working, probably because I have different version of awk. I will download the new one and try again! Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner in GNU `awk`

```
awk -v sp="_length_" 'BEGIN {FS=" |"sp }
    {print $1, $3 > "output"; print $1sp$2, $1 > "log"}' file1
```

Output

```
cat output
NODE_13 GTTGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_25 TATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_36 TGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAG

cat log
NODE_13_length_50291_cov_8.067223 NODE_13
NODE_25_length_22118_cov_8.258986 NODE_25
NODE_36_length_15273_cov_5.283743 NODE_36
```

Comment: This worked very well! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command  and worked fine

first out1

```
awk '{print substr($1,1,7),$NF}'  filename

output

NODE_13 GTTGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_25 TATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_36 TGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAG
```

Second out

```
awk '{print $1,substr($1,1,7)}' filename
```

output

```
NODE_13_length_50291_cov_8.067223 NODE_13
NODE_25_length_22118_cov_8.258986 NODE_25
NODE_36_length_15273_cov_5.283743 NODE_36
```

python method

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('q.txt','r')
for i in  k:
    j=i.split(' ')
    print j[0][0:7],j[1].strip()
print "\n"
q=open('q.txt','r')
for i in q:
    w=i.split(' ')
    print w[0],w[0][0:7]



output
First output1

NODE_13 GTTGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_25 TATCGCCAATCCAGCTCCT
NODE_36 TGCCTAATATCGCCAATCCAG


Second output

NODE_13_length_50291_cov_8.067223 NODE_13
NODE_25_length_22118_cov_8.258986 NODE_25
NODE_36_length_15273_cov_5.283743 NODE_36
```